# Is it a good idea to host Java JAX-RS web services on IIS?

Tags: java, iis, jax-rs, iis-7.5, weblogic12c

We are required to build some Java JAX-RS web services that will connect to some other external web services to retrieve data. Logically, we should host these new JAX-RS web services on a container like WebLogic. Due to cost saving measures by management, we are told to use IIS to host these JAX-RS web services as it is supposedly cheaper than WebLogic. They want the services to be written in Java because it is OS independent, so using .NET is out of the question.

(1) Is using IIS to host Java JAX-RS web services instead of a fully J2EE compliant container like WebLogic to save cost a good idea?

(2) How do we host Java JAX-RS web services on IIS 7.5? What are the required add ons?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **IIS does not support Java**. See this [old post in MSDN (2005)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david.wang/2005/10/11/how-does-jsp-work-on-iis/)

> IIS can never directly support the use of JSP because it requires an add-on to run Java code in a JVM to Load,

Therefore you always require a J2EE server to execute J2EE services, and the IIS add-on `isapi_redirect` (see the link). The add-on will capture the requests and forward them to the J2EE server (in the example is used `tomcat`)

So the answer to your question

> (1) Is using IIS to host Java JAX-RS web services instead of a fully J2EE compliant container like WebLogic to save cost a good idea?

**No, because you allways need a J2EE server.**, so the cost parameter is non applicable (without considering other aspects). I suggest also to consider some free of charge servers like [Jboss](http://www.jboss.org/), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)

Note also you do not need a fully compliant J2EE server to use JAX-RS. Latest versions of JVM are shipped with an implementation of JAX-RS.

Comment: Why would anyone use an add-on in IIS to direct request to  J2EE server, when you can just send the request to the J2EE server directly? Is the add-on supposed to work as a reverse proxy? But if we are talking about reverse proxy, IIS has URL Rewrite module for that already.

Comment: _Why would anyone use an add-on in IIS to direct request to J2EE server, when you can just send the request to the J2EE server directly?_ --> I do not know of any cases. But it is common to use a proxy like Apache or nginx in front of J2EE server to manage SSL and virtual hosts

Comment: _Is the add-on supposed to work as a reverse proxy?_ Reverse proxy Is a function of the front server. The connector should not be noticed. See options for tomcat here: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html

Comment: Hi @user3573403, did the answer solves your question?

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm still not clear. When using IIS with the isapi_redirect add-on, does it mean that this is merely acting as a reverse proxy then?

Comment: Yes, isapi_redirect acts as a filter for each in-coming request. The filter then tests the request URL against a list of URI-paths.If the current request matches one of the entries in the list of URI-paths, the filter transfers the request and the parameter to the J2ee server. Isapi_redirect waits the response and returns it to the browser